# How to prevent someone accessing my iMac

Tags: security, desktop

My desktop is in the living room where anyone visiting can access it.  I'd like to make it secure from those in my home since I have a roommate.

Comment: Lock the screen everytime you leave it or do you need other security - note that physical access to the mac will allow complete access if they reboot it to sing;e user mode

Comment: @Mark Which can easily be prevented.

Answer (score 3):

You can't make it *truly* secure; there is a saying that says given enough time, physical access is root access. That being said, there are some steps you can take to get as close as possible.

## FileVault

Enable filevalult. This will keep people from accessing your data if they boot from an external drive.
To do this, go to `System Preferences` -> `Security & Privacy` -> `FileVault`, and click `Turn On FileVault`. This will most likely require an admin password, and will probably take a very long time, depending on how much stuff is on your computer. That being said, it's worth it.

## Screen lock

Enable auto-locking of your computer after a set amount of time. This can be done in `System Preferences` -> `Security & Privacy` -> `General`. Check the box that says `require password [5 minutes] after sleep or screensaver begins` and change it to your desired amount of time.

## Firmware lock

To prevent booting into single user mode or from an external disk without a password, enable firmware lock.

**WARNING: THIS IS VERY HARD TO RECOVER FROM IF YOU LOSE YOUR PASSWORD. DON'T LOSE IT.**

To do this, shut down your computer and turn it on while holding the <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> keys. This will put you in recovery mode. Click the Utilities menu, and select the Firmware Password Utility. Click `Turn On Firmware Password...` and set a password. You will need it to boot from anything other than your main partition, so keep it safe! If you have an older Mac (Pre-2011, I think) there is a trick to get around this, but it requires removing the RAM, so it's pretty unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

There's never a way to make it entirely secure, especially with physical access. However, you can significantly increase the difficulty.

I would recommend following [this guide](http://docs.hardentheworld.org/OS/OSX_10.11_El_Capitan/) by hardentheworld.org to harden OS X. It's pretty long, but I'll list the steps quickly here: bold is more important.

- Allow only signed apps
- Check Privacy permissions
- Destroy FileVault Keys
- Disable Bonjour
- Disable Creation of Metadata Files
- Disable Diagnostics
- **Disable Guest user**
- Disable Handoff
- Disable password hints
- Disable recent items
- Disable Spotlight localization
- Disable Spotlight Suggestions
- **Enable FileVault**
- **Enable Firewall**
- Enable screen saver
- Empty trash securely
- Erase free space
- Power off memory during standby
- **Require an administration password**
- **Require password to un-lock**
- Save to Disk by Default
- **Set a Firmware Password**
- Show all filename extensions
- Show when localization is used
- Users privilege separation

In addition, I'd recommend the following:

- [Enable secure virtual memory](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18639?locale=en_US) (it's on by default)
- Separate your user account from your administrator one